# copy_to object property field to main document field

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have my models as:

```
class Entity
{
   public List<Prop> PropList { get; set; }

   public List<string> Props { get; set; }

   // others
}

class Prop
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

I want to copy all `Prop's.Names` in `PropList` to `List<string> Props` so that they are include in `_source`.

Is that possible with elasticsearch `copy_to`?

I tried the following, which didn't work,

```
.Mappings(des => des
   .AutoMap()
   .Properties(propsDes => propsDes
      .Object<Prop>(objDes => objDes
        .Name(propDes => propDes.PropList)
        .AutoMap()
        .Properties(objPropsDes => objPropsDes
           .Text(s => s
              .Name(e => e.Name)
              .CopyTo(fieldDes => fieldDes.Field("props"))
           )
         )
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: `PropList` will be included in `_source` by default. Is there a reason you'd like to also copy them to `Props`? You can still query on the names in `PropList`, but you likely want to map them as `nested` data type rather than `object`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: I want to search across multiple indices/types. other types will just have `Props` field which is just the list of `names` without `tags`.